# Как сделать генерацию чисел последовательно

Tags: c#

Есть число `0,000099999999999999999999999999`. Как сгенерировать диапазон чисел от этого числа до `0,999999999999999999999999999999`.В итоге должно получиться

```
0,000099999999999999999999999999
0,000100000000000000000000000000
0,000100000000000000000000000001
...
0,999999999999999999999999999999
```

Comment: У вас в описании начальное и конечное значения диапазона совпадают.

Comment: пардон. Поправил

Comment: У стандартных числовых типов в C# не хватит точности (в знаках после запятой) выражения некоторых чисел из последовательности. какой тип у элементов последовательности вы ожидаете? double?

Comment: Вас кстати не смущает, что вам нужно сгенерировать почти 10^30 чисел? Вы их даже сохранить никуда не сможете.. Куда вам столько и для чего?

Comment: @PashaPash, а у decimal?

Comment: @Grundy, [почти](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/364x0z75.aspx): 28-29 значащих цифр. Может через строки, в цикле от 0 до 9, а затем увеличиваем разряд цифры слева на 1....?

Comment: может опишите задачу, которую решаете, что-то мне подсказывает, что вы что-то не то делаете. За время полного перебора такого диапазона успеет родиться, состариться и сгинуть десяток другой вселенных, последовательно разумеется =)

Comment: Мне кажется, что человек просто хотел узнать как работать с числами большей точности, чем decimal, но не знал как спросить и привел это через не очень корректный пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace BigDec
{
    using Deveel.Math;
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            MathContext mc = new MathContext(26);
            BigDecimal delta=new BigDecimal(1, 25, mc);
            BigDecimal start = new BigDecimal(1, 4, mc).Subtract(delta);

            for (; start != 1; start=start+delta)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(start.ToPlainString());
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Предварительно добавить из nuGet `dmath`

Comment: за 1 млн лет программа выполнится?

Comment: @4per ~10^22 лет, точнее считать лень было, ну может ошибся на 3-5 порядков, я не учитывал скорость вычислений машиной, но это погоды не делает.

Comment: @4per, иногда важен сам процесс, а не результат ;)

Comment: Напомнило [про GUID'ы](http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2013/10/help-me-optimize-this-code-which-enumerates-all-possible-GUIDs.html).

Answer (score -4):

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}
```

Эта функция работает. Но при этом она некорректна: вероятность получить крайние значения min и max будет в два раза меньше, чем любые другие.

При многократном запуске этого кода вы легко заметите, что 2 выпадает чаще всех.

Это происходит из-за того, что Math.round() получает разнообразные случайные числа из интервала от 1 до 3, но при округлении до ближайшего целого получится, что:

значения из диапазона 1   ... 1.49999..  станут 1
значения из диапазона 1.5 ... 2.49999..  станут 2
значения из диапазона 2.5 ... 2.99999..  станут 3
Отсюда явно видно, что в 1 (как и 3) попадает диапазон значений в два раза меньший, чем в 2. Из-за этого такой перекос.

Comment: Я имел в виду не просто рандомно генерить, а последовательно

Comment: @S.Kost топикастеру нужны все числа из диапазона. это как ради получения последовательности 1, 2, ... 10 генерировать рандом 1000 раз, а потом сортировать - почти всегда сработает.